# Using Interface without using argument in function on laravel

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5

i developing a laravel 5 package and now i want to use: interface Gate, on laravel.

in order to use interfaces, i should do by this way:

```
     public function boot(GateContract $gate)
      {
...code...

$gate->define($permission->name)

    ...Codes...
       }
```

but i want to know is there another way use **GateContract $gate** without using **argument** of function or with using **extend** from class.

i mean, can i use like this way:

```
$gate = new Gate;
```

or any thing else,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
$gate = $this->app->make('Gate');
```

There is more information about the Laravel Service container which instantiates objects over here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container